# Using Regex to split math equations

Tags: java, regex

So I am trying to split a simple mathematical equation containing two doubles in scientific notation, e.g "54E-1-57E-1". I'm trying to find regex pattern to do this for me, but I have come across two problems. The first is, the following code splits my string successfully but for some reason negTest prints out false, and I have no idea why.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String testString = "54E-1-57E-1";
    boolean negTest = string.contains("(?<=\\d)-(?=\\d)");
    System.out.println(negTest);
    String[] output = testString.split("(?<=\\d)-(?=\\d)");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));
}

//Output:
//false
//[54E-1, 57E-1]
```

I assume it is a problem with my regex, but the string splits successfully around the minus which confuses me. The second problem is how would I split it so that the minus is included in the second term, e.g.

```
[54E-1, -57E-1]
```

Any help/explanations are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1>`contains` doesn't take regex as a parameter..So you are trying to match `(?<=\\d)-(?=\\d)` as a string not regex

2>To include `-`,your regex should be

```
(?<=\\d)(?=-\\d)
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! Is there another method to check if the string contains that specific regex?

Comment: @JeremyRobertson `matches` method takes regex as a parameter..so you can do this `boolean negTest=string.matches(".*\\d-\\d.*")`